# Error: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: Switch (Skipping no host matched)

Tags: ansible

I have created the basic ansible playbook. But when I run the playbook I am seeing the following error.

```
kiranm@kmalla-lt:~/ansible/playbooks$ ansible-playbook switch.yaml -i host,
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: Switch

PLAY [Switch] ******************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************

kiranm@kmalla-lt:~/ansible/playbooks$
```

My Playbook

```
---
- hosts: Switch
  gather_facts: false
  connection: network_cli
  tasks:
   - name: Run show version on remote devices
     ios_command:
      commands: show run
      host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
      username: kmalla
      password: admin
      register: config
   - name: save output to /ansible/backups
     copy:
       content: "{{ config.stdout[0] }}"
       dest: "/ansible/backups/show_run_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

Host File

```
[Switch]

[ios]
CL-QTS-R1-EDGE01 ansible_host=10.101.0.105


[ios:vars]
ansible_network_os=ios
```

Both my play book and hostfile are in same directory. Can someone please help me on the same where is my mistake.

Comment: please format your question. You have something multi-line here and I can't parse it. As far as I can see, you have `hosts: switch` and your inventory is `host,`, which has no 'switch' group.

Comment: Hi George, I have edited. Please check and let me know

Comment: Hi George, I have edited the post now.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this, highly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in the comment, your play is assigned to the group or host with name 'Switch'. When you pass inventory in comma form (`-i host,`) you provide only one host with name 'host' (and that's all). There is no group 'Switch' in this list, so Ansible  skips playbook assigned to 'Switch'.

Comment: Thanks George, so where I need to modify my code. I would like to connect one switch with IP 10.101.0.105 which is in remote location. Please help me on the same as I am beginner

Comment: replace `hosts: Switch` with `hosts: (stuff you put in command line after -i)`.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for that, now I have following error. Can you please let me know where I need to input the command and configure manually.      Error: TASK [Run show version on remote devices] 
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unable to automatically determine host network os. Please manually configure ansible_network_os value for this host"}

PLAY RECAP 
host                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0